# Ffmpeg headers do not compile in windows

Tags: c++, c, windows, ffmpeg

I am trying to link to ffmpeg under windows, but have run into difficulties. Inclusion of ffmpeg headers causes hundreds of compilation errors which i can't easily fix.

1) timestamp.h uses snprintf instead of _snprintf. I have tried to add it as a macro, like this:

> ```
> #ifdef Q_OS_WIN
> #define snprintf _snprintf
> #endif
>
> #define __STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS 
> namespace ffmpeg { 
> extern "C" {
> #include <libavutil/imgutils.h>
> #include <libavutil/samplefmt.h>
> #include <libavutil/timestamp.h>
> #include <libavformat/avformat.h>
> #include <libswscale/swscale.h> 
> } }
> ```

but it didn't help. Why would the macro not propagate inside?

2) There again, PRId64 isn't defined. I have defined __STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS before inclusion of timestamp.h, but definition isn't retrieved from inttypes.h

In compiler output, it looks like:

```
ffmpeg\include\libavutil/timestamp.h(42) : error C3861: 'snprintf': identifier not found

ffmpeg\include\libavutil/timestamp.h(42) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before
```

identifier 'PRId64'

Comment: Perhaps you should try `#if _WIN32` instead of this `Q_OS_WIN` macro I've never seen before.

Comment: Well, since it nesessitates inclusion of Qt headers (at least QtGlobal), it does make sense to exchange it for non-framework-specific variant.

Answer (score 4):

You did include them into a `extern "C"` right?

```
extern "C" {
#include <libavutil/imgutils.h>
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libswscale/swscale.h>
}
```

Comment: This is almost certainly the problem. OP seems to be writing C++ and unaware the FFmpeg is C.

Comment: yes, i did include them. Also, in ffmpeg namespace. I will put it into question for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

Is this a typo? You talk about "snprintf" ("n", not "m").

```
#define smprintf _snprintf
```

Even then, timestamp.h probably redifines it or includes something that does.